# Mixer and control systems

Tags: audio, frequency-domain, control-systems, laplace-transform

A mixer in the time domain usually multiplies 2 signals of the time domain , however what does it do in the Laplace domain?Is there a equivalent block diagram of a mixer in the Laplace domain?The convolution between those 2 signals right?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Are you asking for the Laplace transform of a mixing block/system?

Comment: No the summer and a block are defined in the Laplace domain, however a mixer is defined in the time domain so I was wondering if we had a mixer which block would define it in the Laplace domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we define "frequency domain" as the Fourier Transform: multiplication in one domain is equivalent to convolution in the other domain. So  multiplication in time is the same as convolution in frequency.

Convolution can be linear or circular depending on what flavor of Fourier Transform we are using (discrete, continuous, periodic, aperiodic, etc)